# How do I force call of labels autoposition algorithm?

Tags: jsxgraph

I'm trying to use JSXGraph 1.00.0 for drawing a sketch (just points and lines). All the point labels are created with "autoPosition: true". Automatic positioning works fine after first user action (a point moving, or an element deletion). But before the first action, the autoposition algorithm does not run. How do I force run it?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `board.update()`. The autoposition algorithm is still considered experimental. If you have a small example which does not work as expected, please open an an issue at github and post the code.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but for some reason not straightforward. I found that call of `board.update()` does not work, but `setTimeout(function() {
    console.debug('labels layout hack');
    board.update();
  }, 0);` does. Yes, `console.debug` call is important as well.

Comment: Not a very small example that demonstrates two issues with the update is here: https://github.com/geometer/sandbox. After pulling the repo, open the file `examples/napoleon.html`. It works fine, but the js contains two hacks.

Comment: 1) in `html/sandbox.js`, line 56, you can see the issue I described above. Replacing the `setTimeout` call with just `update()` breaks the image on the page.

Comment: 2) Another one is two update calls on line 182 of `html/sandbox.js`. To reproduce the issue, comment one of two consequent calls, then in the right part of the page click blue `△A_2B_2C_2`. New elements are added on the sketch, but with single `update()` call the algorithm does not work properly.

Comment: PS Added tag [jsxgraph-issue](https://github.com/geometer/sandbox/tree/jsxgraph-issue) that guarantees you take the version with the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comments were extremely helpful to localize the problem: the autoposition algorithm needs to know the width and height of each each text element. But JSXGraph has to use `setTimeout` in order to wait for the availability of these values. Therefore, your approach to defer the update by `setTimeout` is completely correct. I must confess that I do not yet have a solution which solves the problem out of the box, but I'm working on it.

Comment: Seems like release 1.1.0 fixes this. Great!